# .load start new path

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

in my project im trying to add a modal bootstrap to 1 of my views and i use `.load()` to load that view, the thing is when i try to load the view it only appears black, i tried to use `console.log()` to watch the errors and i saw this

`http://localhost:38212/Desafios/Details/Solucoes/Details?id=14`

when i click the div to trigger the modal, i am in `/Desafios/Details`, and I want to go to `/Solucoes/Details` and not all the url, I don't want to add the `.load()` url to the previous url that i had. How can i do that?

Here is my jquery function

```
$("#VisualizarSolucao").click(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#modal").load("../Solucoes/Details?id=" + id, function () {
        $("#modal").modal();
    })
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

i am loading the js in a external file, here is the VisualizarSolucao id that is called on the click event

```
<div class="col-md-10" style="border-left:2px solid black">
    <p style="text-align:left;padding-top:5px">
        <a href="" id="VisualizarSolucao" data-id="@i.SolucaoId" style="font-weight:900">@i.SolucaoTitulo</a>
    </p>
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8" style="text-align:right">
        <text>Criado por <a href="#">@i.User.UserName</a> no dia @i.DataCriacao</text>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Always use the UrlHelper methods - `.load('@Url.Action("Details", "Solucoes")', { id: id }, function() {`

Comment: not working still giving the same error :S

Comment: Is this script in the view or an external file?

Comment: it is a external file why?

Comment: Then explain that in your question (because its important). And show how you currently generating the element with `id="VisualizarSolucao"`

Comment: i updated the question you are right

Comment: You code suggests that in a loop - is that correct (if so you also have invalid html)

Comment: yeah i know i am changing the invalid html, but i didnt understand the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url in the `.load()` function would need to be `"/Solucoes/Details?id=" + id`, however you should always use the `@Url.Action()` method to ensure your url's as correctly generated.

Since the script is in an external file, and razor code is not parsed in external files, change you html to

```
<a href="#" class="VisualizarSolucao" data-url="@Url.Action("Details", "Solucoes", new { id = i.SolucaoId })">
```

Note that the `id` is changed to a `class` name (your generating duplicate `id` attributes in a loop which is invalid html). You should also remove the inline styles and use css instead.

Then change the script to (no need for `event.preventDefault()`)

```
$('.VisualizarSolucao').click(function() { // class name selector
    var url = $(this).data('url'); // use data(), not attr()
    $("#modal").load(url, function () {
        $("#modal").modal();
    })
});
```

Comment: now it doesnt load anything even the black window of the modal doesnt appear :/

Comment: Of course it does assuming your other code is correct. Put a breakpoint on the `Details()` method of `SolucoesController` - is it being hit?

Comment: url is undefined on the script

Comment: Then you have not copied the code in my answer correctly.